# JQuery mobile Two column grids inside buttons don't fill the width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, pug

I'm trying to create 2 columns grid and to let the buttons fill the column width but the buttons don't fill all the width of the column. Here is my Jade template code:

```
fieldset.ui-grid-a
          div.button.ui-block-a
             input.button(type='submit',data-inline='true',value='Sign In',data-transition='fade',data-theme='a',style='width: 100%;')
          div.ui-block-b   
             a.button(href='/signup',data-inline='true', data-role='button',data-theme='b')
               label Sign Up
```

What is going wrong with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `data-inline='true'` bit from your code. Inline buttons are for when you don't want the button to be full-width.

Here is an example of using an inline button versus a regular one: http://jsfiddle.net/Bh8SE/1/ (as well as an example using a grid)